# Как получить второе число из строки чисел с разделителем?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка чисел разделенных точкой с запятой:

```
2;1;1;1;1;1;5;1;1;1;1;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;1;3;17
```

Не получается получить второе число с начала, в данном случае это `1`.

Перепробовал различные варианты, вот один из последних:

`(?=(^(\d;){1}))\d`

Comment: regexp не нужен. Достаточно поиска первого разделителя и получения символа после него. Что делается через strchr и доступ по индексу, например.

Comment: Какой язык программирования?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew C#

Comment: `var result = s.Split(';').Skip(1).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: самое забавное, что в первой редакции вопроса, можно было просто взять `str[2]` в качестве результата

Comment: @teran, Есть вероятность, что я ошибся, что начал редактировать и единственное не однозначное число в строке - всегда последнее) И регулярка в вопросе намекает...

Comment: @vp_arth а может там в конце просто просто точка с запятой пропущены :)

Comment: @adamshakhabov у вас строка чисел или цифр в итоге-то?

Comment: @teran строка чисел.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В данном случае необязательно использовать регулярное выражение: разбейте на массив значений с `;`, пропустите 1-е и возьмите 2-е:

```
var s = "2;1;1;1;1;1;5;1;1;1;1;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;1;3;17";

var result = s.Split(';').Skip(1).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
Console.Write(result); // => 1

// или
var chunks = s.Split(';');
if (chunks.GetLength(0) > 1) 
    Console.WriteLine(chunks[1]);
```

См. [онлайн-демо](https://ideone.com/i7N3kS)

С помощью регулярного выражения можно найти все последовательности цифр в строке, а потом получить доступ к необходимому значению также как и в первом случае:

```
var chisla = Regex.Matches(s, @"\d+")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Value)
        .ToList();
var my_value = chisla[1]; // => 1
```

Можно использовать и более навороченные констркции:

```
var idx = 2; // Получить второе число в строке
var m = Regex.Match(s, $@"^(?:;?(\d+)){{{idx}}}");
if (m.Success)
{
    Console.Write(m.Groups[1].Value); // => 1
}
```

[Демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/qLGgv9/1)

- `^` - начало строки
- `(?:` - начало незахватываемой группы

  - `;?` - 1 или 0 символов `;`
  - `(\d+)` - 1+ цифр
- `)` - конец незахватываемой группы
- `{{{idx}}}` - найти шаблоны  незахватываемой группы `{idx}` раз (`{{` в интерполированном строковом литерале задаёт `{`, а `}}` — `}`).

Comment: почему не просто ```if (s.Lenght >=2) res = s[1];``` ? это ж быстрее

Comment: @tym32167 `s` — строка. Да, можно и так, с проверкой на длину.

Comment: О, да, я имел ввиду тот код, что вы добавили про ```chunks```, спасибо!

Comment: @tym32167, не забудьте поставить плюсик ответу)

Comment: Понравился фокус с перетиранием группы захвата последним значением

Comment: @vp_arth однозначно плюсик :)

Comment: @vp_arth Честно говоря, я не советую слишком полагаться на этот фокус. Если строка будет очень длинной и надо будет найти 10000-е число, лучше забыть о такой регулярке. Тут единственно правильный подход — это `.Split(';')` и получение значения через индекс.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, а я думал наоборот: так как мне надо обрабатывать по 10 000 тысяч таких строк, то думал что сначала выполнять `Split` и затем по индексу получать число медленнее чем регулярным выражением захватить необходимо число.

Comment: @adamshakhabov Если строки небольшие, то ещё можно пробовать с регуляркой. Количество строк тут параметр второстепенный.

Comment: @adamshakhabov Я только что протестировал своё регулярное выражение и выражение vp_arth на regexhero.net,  и результаты достаточно удручающие при использовании длинных строк (6,5 - 8,5 тыс. итераций в секунду при строке длиной около 1 тыс. знаков). Это очень медленно.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, я вот теперь не уверен, что Split быстрее) Соседний ответ **общий**, можете отредактировать, если там что не так..

Answer (score 5):

Вместо просмотра вперед, нужно использовать [просмотр](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%E5%E3%F3%EB%FF%F0%ED%FB%E5_%E2%FB%F0%E0%E6%E5%ED%E8%FF#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80_%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%91%D0%B4_%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4) назад. Для строки вида

```
2;1;1;1;1;1;5;1;1;1;1;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;1;3;17
```

вполне хватит такой регулярки:

```
/(?<=;)\d+/
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/mRfIVr/1

Comment: Только у Вас выбирает не цифру, а число :))) Но по видимому автор вопроса это и имел в виду.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, из-за `17` я так и предположил.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно использовать положительный просмотр вперед. Больше деталь про регулярные выражения вы найдете [здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Ответ на ваш вопрос выглядит так:
((?<=^\d;)\d)

(?<=^\d;) -  эта часть говорит о том, что перед искомым выражением должна быть одна цифра, точка с запятой и это должны быть первые два символа

Answer (score 1):

Регулярное выражение:

```
^(?:\d+;){1}(\d+)/
```

Мы пропускаем некоторое количество чисел с разделителем и захватываем следующее число.

Демо:

```js
let data = [1, 12, 13, 14, 15];

let str = data.join(';');

console.log(str);


for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  let reg = new RegExp(`^(?:\\d+;){${i}}(\\d+)`);
  console.log(str.match(reg)[1]);
}
```

C#:

```
int index = 2;
string pattern = @"^(?:\d+;){" + index + @"}(\d+)";
string input = "1;23;45;67;89";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(input, pattern).Groups[1].Value); // 45
```

C# (ручной поиск):

```
string result = "";
// Посимвольный проход по строке
for (int charI = 0, numI = 0, N = source.Length; charI < N; ++charI) {
    char current = source[charI]; // Текущий символ
    if (current == separator) {   // Разделитель
        ++numI;
        if (numI > index) break;  // Дальше - не интересно
    } else if (numI == index) {
        // Все символы нужного токена попадают в результат(не только цифры)
        result += current;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Дело в том что у меня массив таких строк `1;12;13;14;15` и я хочу прогнать именно его (массив) через цикл и из каждой строки взять порядковое число. Сейчас необходимо второе. В другом случае понадобиться 3, 4 т. д.

Comment: @adamshakhabov это как то влияет на регулярное выражение что ли?

Comment: а зачем тут группы то в начале, хоть и без захвата, почему не просто `^\d;(\d+)`

Comment: @adamshakhabov, ну так в демо как раз выбираются все числа от 0 до N

Comment: @teran, чтобы параметризовать выборку, разумеется

Comment: тут https://regex101.com/r/UJvFgd/1 к примеру я пытаюсь получить 3 число, но не выходит.

Comment: @adamshakhabov потому что `\d+` а не `\\d+` надо и не `{3}` а `{2}`, это не индекс, а число повторов предыдущей группы

Comment: Добавил код на C#

Comment: @teran, число пропусков эквивалентно индексу, от 0 же

Comment: @vp_arth эквивалентно да, но по сути это число повторов пропускаемой группы. Человеку пытающемуся разобраться в регулярках надо понимать что есть что.

Comment: вот пытаюсь получить 3 число https://regex101.com/r/UJvFgd/3 `^(?:\d+;){2}(\d+)` и снова безуспешно

Comment: @adamshakhabov, почему же безуспешно? Смотрите блок Match Information, строка `Group 1`

Answer (score 0):

Попробовал позамерять.

```
public class Program
{
    private static string getNthNumber(string s, int n, char separator = ';')
    {
        string s_res = "";
        for (int charI = 0, numI = 0, N = s.Length; charI < N; ++charI) {
            char current = s[charI];
            if (current == separator) {
                ++numI;
                if (s_res == "") continue;
                break;
            } else if (numI == n) {
                s_res += current;
            }
        }
        return s_res;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string src = String.Join(";", Enumerable.Range(0, 10000));

        double TEST_SIZE = 15e3; 
        int getIndex = 1100;
        string sum = "";
        int start = Environment.TickCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < TEST_SIZE; ++i)
          sum = Program.getNthNumber(src, getIndex); // 5000
        double duration = Environment.TickCount - start;
        double bandwidth = TEST_SIZE/(duration/1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Manual Bandwidth is " + bandwidth + "test/s");

        start = Environment.TickCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < TEST_SIZE; ++i)
          sum = src.Split(';').Skip(getIndex).FirstOrDefault();
        duration = Environment.TickCount - start;
        bandwidth = TEST_SIZE/(duration/1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Split/Skip Bandwidth is " + bandwidth + "test/s");

        start = Environment.TickCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < TEST_SIZE; ++i)
          sum = Regex.Match(src, @"^(?:\d+;){" + getIndex + @"}(\d+)").Groups[1].Value;
        duration = Environment.TickCount - start;
        bandwidth = TEST_SIZE/(duration/1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Regexp Bandwidth is " + bandwidth + "test/s");
    }
}
```

Запуск в первом попавшемся онлайн сервисе:

> Manual Bandwidth is 64516,1290322581test/s
>   Split/Skip Bandwidth is 1523,22924600152test/s
>   Regexp Bandwidth is 3656,3071297989test/s

Comment: `Take(1)` не нужен

Comment: Я ж не шарпист, копипаста из соседнего ответа

Comment: @Grundy, Думаю там и вручную пооптимальнее возможно, зная особенности языка)